# delete all that are checked in laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox

Hello I want to delete all the rows from the database which are being checked by the user but whenever I do this I get this error `"Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\UploadController::deleteSelectedUploads()"`. I know why this error is coming because I haven't passed any id to it and if I pass any id to it then it says `Undefined variable: upload`. Please help me out. I know I have been posting a lot of questions nowadays and later solve it on my own but this is the only way of learning I guess.

## Controller

```
 public function deleteSelectedUploads($id) {

    //$uploads = $this->upload->get($id);
    // $checkboxes = $this->request->input('checkbox[]');

    // if((Auth::user()->role=='admin')) {
    //     $this->upload->deleteUpload($id);
    // } else {
    //     Session::flash('message', "Oooopsss ... ! seems like you don't have the authority to 
    //     <span style=font-weight:bold;'><u>DELETE</u></span> this file.
    //     <span style='font-size:15pt; font-weight:bold;'> Contact ADMIN </span>");
    //     return redirect('home');
    // }

$checkbox = Input::all();

foreach($checkbox['checkbox'] as $id) {
    Upload::where('id', $id)->delete();
}

    Session::flash('message', 'You File has been deleted');
    return redirect('home');
 }
```

## View

```
<th><form action="/delete-selected-uploads" method="get">

      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" value="Delete all checked">
                    </form>
                  </center>
              </th>

             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="{{ $upload['id'] }}" value="{{$upload['id']}}">
             </td>
```

## Route

```
Route::get('/delete-selected-uploads', 'UploadController@deleteSelectedUploads');
```

Comment: Please provide your full Controller function, including the head part

Comment: Please print the output the ' var_dump(Input::all()); ' or put in any log file or printscreen with that output in the Controller

Comment: I have updated the controller here ...

Comment: var_dump not working ... it gives the same error ... it need the id to perform that method ... `ErrorException in UploadController.php line 104: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\UploadController::deleteSelectedUploads()`

Comment: I have pasted the code below where I defined @foreach to test input::all() and I got only 1 array on everything `array:1 [▼
  "checkbox" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "76"
  ]
]`

Comment: remove the $id parameter on your controller method

Comment: now I got this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` at line `foreach($checkbox['checkbox'] as $id) {`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you maybe put the parameter to

The function `public function deleteSelectedUploads($id) {` it need the parameter $id.

And you call this function avoid `::deleteSelectedUploads()`.

One solutions can be put not requerid the $id parameter as `public function deleteSelectedUploads($id = '') {`

**UPDATE:** Try in the view:

```
<th>
<form action="/delete-selected-uploads" method="get">

      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"/>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" value="Delete all checked">
       <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="{{ $upload['id'] }}" value="{{$upload['id']}}">
        </td>
         </center> 
</th>
</form>
```

I hope help you.

Comment: so how am I supposed to delete the record from the database, if I dont get the id's ?

Comment: I think that you put the id's by parameter intro $checkbox array.

Comment: i didn't ... the code is the same which I have posted here ... I am not passing any parameter into checkbox array ... I am doing this `$checkbox['checkbox']` to get all the checked uploads ... that does not comes under parameter ?

Comment: Not, Sorry my English. $checkbox['checkbox'] are yours parameters. You can modify the deleteSelectedUploads to deleteSelectedUploads($id = null) And you now get all the id's in $checkbox['checkbox'] array.

Comment: it's not taking id in here, in this part of the code `<form action="/delete-selected-uploads" method="get">`